# Passing Trigger DAG Id value xcom

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am building a parent dag that basically does a conditional trigger of another dag depending on a xcom value.

Say, I have the following dags in my system

1. Load Contracts
2. Load Budget
3. Load Sales
4. Trigger Data Loads (Master)

In my master DAG, I have two tasks - (1) Check File Name (2) Trigger appropriate dag based on file name. If File Name is Sales, then trigger 'Load Sales' and like wise for Budget / Contracts.

Here is how my TriggerDAGRunOperator is configure

```
def _check_file_version(**context):
    context["task_instance"].xcom_push(key="file_name",value="Load Sales")
with dag:

    completion_file_check = PythonOperator(
        task_id="completion_file_check"
        python_callable=_check_file_version,
        provide_context=True
    )

    trigger_dependent_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id = "trigger_dependent_dag",
        provide_context=True,
        trigger_dag_id={{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='completion_file_check', key='file_name') }},
        wait_for_completion=True
    )
```

I want to modify the trigger_dag_id value based on the filename. Is there a way to pull in xcom variable value into it? Looking at this link -[DAG Dependencies](https://marclamberti.com/blog/dag-dependencies-in-apache-airflow-the-ultimate-guide/#Implementation_of_the_TriggerDagRunOperator_for_DAG_Dependencies), I see that this value is jinja templated i.e. can be modified using the variables. However, my use case is to have it configured via xcom pull. Can it be done?

When I put in the xcom_pull as suggested by the replies, I get syntax error ass shown below

[image]

Comment: Hi @VKarthik, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ti.xcom_pull to get xcom value that you pushed in previous task.

```
{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='sales_taskid', key='filename_key') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

XCom is identified by key, task_id and dag_id. For your requirement, you can use xcom_pull where you can provide task id and keys. XCom is used for small amounts of data and larger values are not allowed. If the task auto-pushes the results into the XCom key called return_value then, xcom_pull will use that as default value for keys. For more information, you can check this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html).

If you are auto-pushing the results into key, you can use below code :

`value = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='pushing_task')`

For trigger_dag_id value based on the filename, you can use it in template as below :

`{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='your_task_id', key='file_name') }}`

Comment: Adding in the xcom I am getting 'not defined' error when putting in the value directly for trigger_dag_id value. Should this value be added as conf variable? If so, how would it update the name dynamically?

Comment: Hi @VKarthik, can you clarify how you are using the xcom by providing a sample code?

Comment: I updated my original post with the code.

Comment: Hi @VKarthik, can you confirm whether your DAG's are in the same environment or not?